# Some issues with immutable hash  in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the following dumb test code:

```
#lang racket
(define vars '('g1 'g2 'g3 'g1))
(define addrs '(123 456 789 012))

(define immhs (make-immutable-hasheq empty))

(define immhs* (for/fold ([imhs immhs]) ([var (in-list vars)] [addr (in-list addrs) ]) (hash-set imhs var addr )))

immhs*

(hash-ref immhs* 'g1)
```

The output is:

```
'#hasheq(('g1 . 123) ('g2 . 456) ('g3 . 789) ('g1 . 12))
hash-ref: no value found for key: 'g1
```

Why can't the `hash-ref` reference to the `'g1`? (it will also fail on `'g2`, etc)
Then I uses `(hash-keys immhs*)`, it returns `'('g1 'g2 'g3 'g1)`, where there is `'g1`;
and I use further `(car (hash-keys immhs*))`, it returns `''g1` ; then the question is that why there are two quote `'` before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly the two quotes that you see: `x` evaluates to whatever `x` is bound to, `'x` evaluates to a symbol, and `''x` evaluates to a quoted form -- `'x`.  Try this:

```
(define vars '(g1 g2 g3 g1))
```

and it will work.